# Does VueJS make a distinction between function declaration formats under its methods property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Our team is working on a VueJS project and I noticed that some of the method functions are declared this way:

```js
methods: {
    doSomething: function () {
        //do it here...
    }
}
```

while others are in this format:

```js
methods: {
    doSomething() {
        //do it here...
    }
}
```

Both of the formats work just fine and if I remember my javascript correctly, the second method is just a javascript shorthand for function declaration.

But does VueJS makes a distinction between the two formats? What is the best/preferred way to declare VueJS methods? How about VueJS computed functions, does it have to be formatted in the same way as method functions?

Comment: afaik, no, doesn't make a difference. However, I found that if I use the shorthand, then run the .js files through a minimizer, the minimizer throws an exception. So I go with `doSomething: function ()`

Comment: Both is the same. Which one you chose is a matter of taste. Computed properties can be defined the same way, but also allow for specifying getters and setters separately. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Comment: @MichaelTranchida `I found that if I use the shorthand, then run the .js files through a minimizer, the minimizer throws an exception.` Is this really true? We build our code with Webpack and its minified without any error. Or maybe Webpack is doing some of its transpiling magic and converting the shorthand declarations to the classic ones?

Comment: @jimx Dunno, i use the bundler/minimizer in Visual Studio, think it's the one made by Mads. That one throws an exception for me.

Comment: @MichaelTranchida Thanks for the clarification. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with Vue.

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, a shorter syntax for method definitions on objects initializers is introduced. It is a shorthand for a function assigned to the method's name.

Given the following code:

```
var obj = {
  foo: function() {
    /* code */
  },
  bar: function() {
    /* code */
  }
};
```

You are now able to shorten this to:

```
var obj = {
  foo() {
    /* code */
  },
  bar() {
    /* code */
  }
};
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: So out with the old and in with the new, I guess? If we want to follow ES6 standards then go with the shorthand.

Comment: You can follow which ever you like, of course the new one looks shot and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to declare a method

```
methods: {
    doSomething: () => {
        //do it here...
    }
}
```

Actually your ways of declaration is same and you are right - you can use both in same way.

But remember, if you need to access component's instance inside of method (`this`) - arrow function would not let you do that.

```
methods: {
    doSomething: () => {
        console.log(this) // undefined
    }
}
```

In that case you almost always have to use this way:

```
methods: {
    doSomething() {
        console.log(this) // insance
    }
}
```

Comment: Great input thanks! Arrow functions are really something you should watch out for, especially with working with VueJS.

Comment: Might be true but again, it has nothing to do with Vue. It's the property of arrow functions that they use the defining scope and not the calling scope.

Answer (score 0):

well both are objects they can be written any way its not about vue its about js engine over here which does not distinguish between both in any way. with respect to the best practices you should follow https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide its an official guid for the same. certain times if your function is small You can skip

```
methods:{
  xyz(){
  }
}
```

and write it as

```
methods:{
  xyz:()=> return something;
}
```